# How large should the size of array M be in linear probing hash table?

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I tried to understand an implementation of linear probing hash table using Java. However, I am frustrated with understanding why M is given an initial value of 30001. The skeleton of the code is given below.

```
    public class LinearProbingHashTable<Key, Value>{
      private int M = 30001;
      private Value[] vals = (Value[]) new Object[M];
      private Key[] keys = (Key[]) new Object[M];

      private int hash(Key key){...}
      public void put(Key key, Value val){...}
      public Value get(Key key){...}
    }
```

My question is why M is initialised to 30001 here. Is this a rule-of-thumb? How should I decide the size of M when initialising the linear probing hash table?

Comment: The magnitude (i.e. roughly 30k) was probably chosen heuristically to be "good" for "most" use cases (i.e. a trade-off between memory use and reallocation).  The exact value makes it close to prime (not sure why not an actual prime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to know what this part of code serve for in order to understand this better. Maybe, or probably, keys are within [0, 30000].

---

**Further reading**:

1. [[1]](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/niemann/s_has.htm) [[2]](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rentrpt/v1r0m1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.ug_ds.10.1.1.doc%2Fc_initialsizeofthehashtable.html)
   Selecting an appropriate HashTableSize is important to the success of this method. For example, a HashTableSize of two would yield even hash values for even Keys, and odd hash values for odd Keys. This is an undesirable property, as all keys would hash to the same value if they happened to be even. If HashTableSize is a power of two, then the hash function simply selects a subset of the Key bits as the table index. To obtain a more random scattering, **HashTableSize should be a prime number not too close to a power of two.**
2. Check out [[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286058/chosing-a-suitable-table-size-for-a-hash) on how to chose a suitable table size for a Hash.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I added some more info for the long story of choosing a suitable hash table size.

Comment: Ok, but I was merely commenting on your claim "30001 is a prime number" ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I see what you mean. You are right, 30001 is not a prime number as `30001=19*1579`. :-)